# Calling Chai plugin in Intern returns error

Tags: node.js, dojo, requirejs, intern

I was trying to use the [sinon-chai plugin](http://chaijs.com/plugins/sinon-chai) within Intern but it gave me:

```
Error {stack: (...), message: "Cannot find the Node.js require"}
```

I had installed the plugin via npm and here's my test file:

```
define([
  'intern!bdd',
  'intern/chai!expect',
  'app/functions',
  'intern/chai',
  'intern/dojo/node!sinon-chai'
], function (bdd, expect, myapp, chai, sinonChai) {
  chai.use(sinonChai);

  ...

});
```

What might go wrong?

Comment: Have you browerified it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The node loader requires Node.js, so it can't be used in the browser. You'll need to load the sinon-chai library directly, as shown below (assuming the relative path from your test to `node_modules` is `../node_modules`):

```
define([
  'intern!bdd',
  'intern/chai!expect',
  'app/functions',
  'intern/chai',
  '../node_modules/sinon-chai/lib/sinon-chai'
], function (bdd, expect, myapp, chai, sinonChai) {
  chai.use(sinonChai);
  ...
});
```

You could simplify the test include by defining a sinon-chai package in your intern config:

```
...
loader: {
    { name: 'sinon-chai', location: 'node_modules/sinon-chai/lib' },
    ...
}
...
```

Then you could get by with just:

```
define([
    ...
    'sinon-chai/sinon-chai'
], function (bed, expect, myapp, chai, sinonChai) {
...
});
```

Comment: this is how I integrated `chai-spies` library for my intern setup. One thing to note, I had to install chai lib separately in my package.json and in my test file I included the chai lib from the node_modules folder in order to use `chai.use()` method