# How can I verify that a method has been called with intern test framework?

Tags: javascript, testing, web, typescript, intern

I'm using [The Intern test framework](https://theintern.github.io) for testing my web application. Now I need to verify that a method has been invoced during a test, but I cannot find any resource which describes that this is possible with e.g. chai!assert or bdd. Can you give me a hint how I can accomplish a verification of a method invocation during test?

Comment: Looks like either one of [sinon](https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon) with [sinon-chai plugin](https://github.com/domenic/sinon-chai) or [chai-spies](https://github.com/chaijs/chai-spies) could do the job. There's even [question answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25995984/calling-chai-plugin-in-intern-returns-error) on how to use sinon-chai with intern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a standard built-in way to do this, but there are several ways to go about it. As @artem suggested, sinon works with Intern and has the ability to stub out methods on objects. If you're testing Dojo code, you can use `dojo/aspect` to add aspect advice to a method and use that to record that the method was called. You can also just use the plain JavaScript technique of replacing the function of interest with a stub, like `var called = false; someObject.myMethod = function () { called = true; };`.

Comment: Yes I'm using dojo toolkit to build the application. I stumbled earlier over [sinon](http://sinonjs.org). I'll give it a try. Thank you!